# Generate time series off of two date fields (redshift, sql)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, generate-series

I would like to create a time series using two date fields as a basis in redshift via a query. For example, let's suppose I have a table like below:

| ID | Stage | Entered On | Exited On |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8881 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-01 |
| 8881 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-04 |
| 8881 | Stage 3 | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-08 |
| 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 8882 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-06 |

Using the `entered on` and `exited on` fields, I'd like to create a daily snapshot per ID/stage. The desired output would look something like this:

| Date | ID | Stage | Entered On | Exited On |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-28 | 8881 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-01-29 | 8881 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-01-30 | 8881 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-01-31 | 8881 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-02-01 | 8881 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-28 | 2021-02-01 |
| 2021-02-01 | 8881 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-02 | 8881 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-03 | 8881 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-04 | 8881 | Stage 3 | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-08 |
| ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
| 2021-01-30 | 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-01-31 | 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-01 | 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-02 | 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-03 | 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-04 | 8882 | Stage 1 | 2021-01-30 | 2021-02-04 |
| 2021-02-04 | 8882 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-08 |
| 2021-02-05 | 8882 | Stage 2 | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-08 |
| ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... |

I know I can use a CTE to generate the time series in memory but can't figure out the best way to relate that back to create the historical time series off the two dates. I'm assuming there is a join here I could do based on whether entered on or exited on is greater than or equal to the date from the time series but have had no luck so far. When I try that, I get the following error:

**[0A000] ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.**

Any help here would be much appreciated and thank you in advance!

````
    (select (getdate()::date - generate_series)::date
from generate_series(1,2000,1)) ```
````

Comment: Redshift is not Postgres.  I removed the Postgres tag.

Comment: Ahh, I know Redshift is semi-based off Postgres which is why I included it

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, my logic was correct - it had to do with the generate series portion and how redshift handles that function. I should have dug into this more earlier. If I use something like this and put in a CTE:

```
( SELECT DATEADD('day', -n, (CURRENT_DATE+1)) AS generated_date
   FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n FROM my_table) n
   ORDER BY generated_date DESC)
```

And then join that against my first table using the following condition:

```
on t.generated_date>=entered_on and t.generated_date<=exited_on
```

It produces the desired output.